# Merge items in laravel collections with same id and sum other columns

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection like this:

[image]

I want to merge or unifi the "rows" that have the same "referencia" and sum the last columns  if exists...(t1_total,t2_total,t3_total...)

```
foreach ($compo_escandallo as $row) {
        $scandal->subtotal = $scandal->subtotal + $row->importe;
        if ($row->um == "M") { /**&& $row->merma != 0 */
            ($row->merma) / 100;
        } else {
            $row->merma;
        }
        if ($row->tipo == "MMPP") {
            $total_mmpp = $total_mmpp + $row->importe;
        }
        if ($row->xtalla == "X") {
            //$consumo = 0;
            foreach ($tallas as $talla){
                if($talla->tallan=="001" or $talla->tallan=="075" or $talla->tallan=="S"){
                    $row->t1_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t1) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="002" or $talla->tallan=="080" or $talla->tallan=="M"){
                    $row->t2_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t2) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="003" or $talla->tallan=="085" or $talla->tallan=="L"){
                    $row->t3_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t3) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="004" or $talla->tallan=="090" or $talla->tallan=="XL"){
                    $row->t4_total =  ($this->floatvalue($row->t4) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="005" or $talla->tallan=="095" or $talla->tallan=="XXL"){
                    $row->t5_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t5) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="006" or $talla->tallan=="100"){
                    $row->t6_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t6) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="007" or $talla->tallan=="105"){
                    $row->t7_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t7) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="008" or $talla->tallan=="110"){
                    $row->t8_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t8) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="009" or $talla->tallan=="115"){
                    $row->t9_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t9) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="010" or $talla->tallan=="120"){
                    $row->t10_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t10) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }elseif($talla->tallan=="011" or $talla->tallan=="125"){
                    $row->t11_total = ($this->floatvalue($row->t11) + ($this->floatvalue($row->merma)/100)) * $this->floatvalue($row->veces);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    $filtered_collection = $compo_escandallo->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->xtalla == 'X';
    })->values();
```

Not in all cases have 11 totals, sometimes have 3 or 4 totals only, as see in picture. How can i do this? I try some examples in stackoverflow as:

```
`$unique = $compo_escandallo->unique('referencia'); 

    $unique->transform(function ($item, $key) use ($compo_escandallo) {
        //dd($item->referencia);
        $id = $item->referencia;
    
        $item->referencia = $compo_escandallo->sum(function ($product) use ($id) {
            dd($product);
            if($product->referencia == $id){
                return $product->t1_total;
            }
        });
        return $item;
    });
    return $unique->all();`
```

But not work as i expect and no return the collection as i need.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: To understand more about ur question, you have a list of data inside a collection and you want to unify all the records that have the same referencia?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Kneegrows, if the item[0] in collection ( first array) has same reference of other item[i], i want to have only one row or array with this reference and the totals added

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) method of the collection and then map the totals something like :-

```php
   use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

   // $data = your fetched item from the db
   $collected_data = new Collection($data)->groupBy('referencia');

   // now that you have the data sorted according the ref, sum their totals
   $collected_data = $collected_data->eachSpread(function ($item, $key) {
      return $item['grand_total', $item->sum('t1_total', 't3_total')];
   });
```

hope that helps, tweak the variables and the nesting of the code to your specific need.